# Split string with commas to new line repeating the string

Tags: python

I have a .csv file with rows like: `apple,banana,orange,carambola` and `red,blue,purple,black`

And I am trying to split like: 
`apple,banana`
`apple,orange`
`apple,carambola` and 
`red,blue`
`red,purple`
`red,black`

How do I do that?

**Update**
[AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpQHt.png)

**Update 2**
[AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye5jI.png)

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're hoping to do. Have you tried anything yourself yet? If so, please show us your attempt. If not, give it a shot yourself, then come back here when you have a specific question about implementation. Stack Overflow isn't really meant to give general advice, we're here more for assistance with very specific problems with code.

Comment: Here's what I tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpQHt.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye5jI.png

Comment: You need to post your code as text, in your question. And if you're using pandas, add the pandas tag.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to add the first element of your row to all of others in the row. You can do like this:

```
row = 'apple,banana,orange,carambola'
splitted_row = row.split(",")
print ([",".join([splitted_row[0], i]) for i in splitted_row[1:]])
# ['apple,banana', 'apple,orange', 'apple,carambola']
```

Comment: I think I did something wrong. appears: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'. image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpQHt.png

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate for each row of your csv file and do something like that:

```py
csv_row = csv_row.split(',')
new_list = []
for i in range(1,len(csv_row)):
    new_list.append(','.join((csv_row[0],csv_row[i])))
```

Comment: I think I did something wrong. appears: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'. image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye5jI.png

Comment: @bolota the thing is: you're trying to split a DataFrame object. Split is a string method. I see you're using Pandas. You didn't mention it in your question. What you need to do is open the csv file with ```csv``` module OR iterate through every row of your df. The code I put above would be the inner for loop. You'd have to have something like ```for row in df:``` and then ```csv_row = row.split(',')```